# How to show console window when executing external jar?

Tags: java, cmd

When starting an external Java application, I'd also like to see the console window. From what I've read this should be possible when executing `cmd /c start xyz`. However, by using the following code, I am getting the error message "Windows cannot find '-jar'".

```
String s = "cmd /c start \"C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre6/bin/java.exe\" -jar myjar.jar param1=x param2=y";
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(s);
```

If `start` isn't included the application is executed, but the window isn't shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should run correctly

```
String s = "cmd /c start \"C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre6/bin/java.exe\" java -jar myjar.jar param1=x param2=y";
```

Comment: The window is shown now, but there seems to be a problem with the path. The application I am calling can't find a DLL, that is also located in the same directory. I tried setting the path to "." like this: `cmd /c start /d .`, but the DLL still isn't found. Do you know any solution to this problem?

Comment: It might be easier to make a new question with the new problem and the line you're using that now shows cmd and runs the java application.  It's hard to see from a comment what you've been trying.